# Populate Table Based on Dropdown Selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the below dropdown list of months and table. The table needs to display different entries based on the month selected. I am not entirely sure how I can get this table created in the background when the month value changes?

HTML

```
<form id="monthSelect">
    <select id="month">
        <option>January</option>
        <option>February</option>
        <option>March</option>
        <option>April</option>
        <option>May</option>
        <option>June</option>
        <option>July</option>
        <option>August</option>
        <option>September</option>
        <option>October</option>
        <option>November</option>
        <option>December</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="list">
    <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Acc No</th>
            <th>Corp. Name</th>
            <th>Entity</th>
            <th>Year End</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['name'] .'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['entity'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['year_end'].'</td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Ajax

```
$('#month').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : '../src/processes/year-end-report.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                month : month
            },
            success : function (data) {
                $("#list").html(html);
            }
        })
    })
```

PHP

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE year_end = 'DECEMBER'");
```

I am not entirely sure how I can get this table created in the background when the month value changes?

Answer (score 0):

Send the ajax request to the url where your php scrip is, populate the data property of the ajax request with the selected value.

Then on your php script get that value, escape it, and use it in your query.

```
$month = $_GET['month']
```

...

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE year_end = '$month'");
```

Get the array of values you need and use json to encode them, finally echo the json.

Comment: How do I send the Ajax back to the page and create the table?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need to do is -

1. Create a separate file having table tag. 
   So whatever records you are fetching from query based on the month selection, will serve as input to the file.
2. Load that file into the `<div id="list"></div`, every time month is changed.